# How to Add value in map<id,map<string,Boolean>>

Tags: apex

```
public class AccountAllowanceTriggerHandler {
    public void getAccountAndProduct(List<Account_Allowances__c> listAccountAllowance){
        map<id,map<string,Boolean>>map_FamilyWithProductAndActive=new map<id,map<string,Boolean>>();
        String Product='';
        Boolean Is_Active;
        String Account='';

        for(Account_Allowances__c objAA :listAccountAllowance){
            Product=objAA.Products__c;
            Is_Active=objAA.Is_Active__c;
            Account=objAA.Account__c;
        }
        list<Account_Allowances__c> listAA=[Select Id,Products__c,Is_Active__c,Account__c 
                                            From Account_Allowances__c 
                                            Where Products__c=:Product 
                                            And Account__c=:Account];
        if(listAA!=null && listAA.size()>1){
            for(Account_Allowances__c aA:listAA){
                if(aA.Is_Active__c=true){

                //how add value in map==>
                    map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.put(aA.Account__c,(aA.Products__c,aA.Is_Active__c));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please suggest me how to add value in map

Comment: You may have to learn and deep dive into Apex (`Map`) for this, as this is very specific use case for your data model.

Comment: Hi Nagendra thanks for replying, I'm New in coding so I get stuck in small problem, please give me the solution of this . I'm very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a nested map, you have to navigate each layer individually:

```
for(Account_Allowances__c objAA :listAccountAllowance){
    Product=objAA.Products__c;
    Is_Active=objAA.Is_Active__c;
    Account=objAA.Account__c;
    map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.put(objAA.Account__c, new Map<String, Boolean>());
}
for(Account_Allowances__c objAA :listAccountAllowance){
    map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.get(objAA.Account__c).put(objAA.Products__c, objAA.Is_Active__c);
}
```

Note that `Product`, `Is_Active`, and `Account` should be either Lists or Sets, so you can query all the records you need at once.

I'm not sure why you're doing all this, but here's some helpful hints:

```
for(Account_Allowances__c objAA :listAccountAllowance){
    Product=objAA.Products__c;
    Is_Active=objAA.Is_Active__c;
    Account=objAA.Account__c;
}
```

Is overriding the variable each time. This means you're going to query only the last record in the list.

```
    if(listAA!=null && listAA.size()>1){
```

A query result is never null. Also, it is perfectly safe to iterate over an empty list; you don't need either of these conditions.

```
            if(aA.Is_Active__c=true){
```

Watch out for this. Here, you're assigning the value `true` to `aA.Is_Active__c`, which means it'll always be true. Make sure you're using `==`, or even better, don't check with equality; a Boolean is already a Boolean.

```
            if(aA.Is_Active__c){
```

Comment: I'm very thankful to you sfdcfox.

Comment: Its there any way to connect with you...........

Comment: what is the syntax , if i add condition like
if(map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.Boolean value is true){
//perform a code
}

Comment: @debprakashanSunny `if(map_FamilyAndActive.get(accountId).get(productId)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of your map is itself a container, you'll need 2 steps:

1. create the container, if necessary
2. insert your new value

```
if (null == map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.get(aA.Account__c)) {
  map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.put(aA.Account__c, new Map<String, Boolean>());
}
map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.get(aA.Account__c).put(aA.Products__c, aA.Is_Active__c));
```

Comment: what is the syntax , if i add condition like
if(map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.Boolean value is true){
//perform a code
}

Comment: if (map_FamilyWithProductAndActive.get(aA.Account__c).get(aA.Products__c)) {